# how to print vertical character in assembly language

Tags: assembly, emu8086

There is some way to print a character vertically using a loop for example print the 'l' from (0,0) to (0,10) in in assembly language. I'm using emu8086. I mean to go printing in a different row without changing the column

```
org 100h

mov ax, 3
mov ah, 0
mov al, 3
int 10h         

mov cl,10
print:
mov ah,02 
mov bh,0                        
mov dh,cl  ;y
mov dl,0  ; x
int 10h 

mov ah,09  
mov bh,0     
mov bl,00Fh 
mov al,'l'
mov cx, 1  
int 10h 
loop print  

ret
```

[image: Output]

Comment: what do you mean by "print vertically"? Print the `l` as `-` or print each character of a string like `abc` in a single line?

Comment: Yes. There are millions of ways how to do that. If there wouldn't be billions of billions of ways how to screw it, I would even dare to say, that whatever you will try, it will very likely work. (but the letter in text mode will stay upward, unless you modify the font data) => edit your question and add lot more info (rotated letters? what gfx mode? what did you try? what it does? What problem can't you resolve?), as it is now, this is too broad/unclear what is asked

Comment: 8 bits = values 0..255 or -128..+127 (or any other interpretation you dare to code in your code). 16 bits = 0..65535 or -32768..+32767 (or anything else you code over them). `dh` is alias for upper 8 bits of `dx` (16b register). `cx` is 16 bit register. Ordinary `mov` can't handle transformation of different data sizes (`movzx/movsx` can extend values of smaller size). In your case `mov dh,cl` will achieve what you want, because the `cx` wil go only through 10..1 range, while 16 bit register, only 4 bits will be effectively used for such small numbers, so using only the low 8 bits `cl` is OK.

Comment: This link looks to contain all keywords of my search: https://www.cs.uaf.edu/courses/cs301/2014-fall/notes/bits/  ... which gives it some chance that it provides enough details about the topic (how values are encoded in bits, what effective ranges are covered, and the x86 registers description), but I didn't read it through if it's really good. BTW, if you will understand all that, you should be able to tell why the second `int 10h` will do the same thing even if the 4x `mov` setup will be replaced by two: `mov ax,0900h+'l'` `mov bx,0CAh`

Comment: @Ped7g Now my problem is that a pyramid comes out and I just want it to be a character in each row. Try putting cx in 1 but abort the loop. What am I doing wrong? Sorry for the inconvenience. I'm new to assembler.

Comment: `mov cx, 1` will change `cx` value, which is used as loop counter ... also ahead of loop you do `mov cl,10`, that's wrong, because the `loop print` will use `cx`, not only `cl` `mov cx,10` was better... around second `int 10h` you can do `push cx mov cx,1 int 10h pop cx` to save loop counter. I'm still too lazy to check the actual `int 10h` service calls docs to see if you are using them correctly. Also using debugger and stepping over single instructions may be very illustrative to better understand the text description of instruction in the instruction reference guide (use that too).

Comment: (sorry, this is sort of funny, IIRC there are sometimes people asking how to print pyramid in emu8086, struggling with it... and there you go, not wanting it, yet done... :) ) *giggle*  (that push/pop quick fix of `cx` is sort of ugly/slow performance... then again using `int 10h` to output anything in DOS text mode is super slow, so who cares about tiny malus of `push/pop` pair ... but using some other register as loop counter and restoring all w/o stack memory would be more optimal)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help that has solved my problem. I will study everything you have put. It has saved my day.

Comment: at the beginning of the loop I put mov di, cx and after executing the instruction int 10h I put mov cx, di. That was the way you said you could do more optimal?

Comment: You could just use `di` for your loop counter and loop with `dec di / jnz`.  `loop` is slow anyway, so it's not a good habit to learn unless you're *actually* optimizing for a real 8086 (or optimizing for code-size, but then it still shouldn't be a "habit", just one possible way of doing a dec-and-branch in 2 bytes.)

Comment: Yes, good try. But ultimately you can just do `mov dx,0A00h ; dh = 10, dl = 0` (ahead of `print:`), that will already set `dh:dl` for first `int 10h`, and then the looping mechanism can work with y coordinate like `dec dh` `jnz print` - all done, no registry shuffling needed, not even additional register needed (separate counter vs y-coord), `cx` can then be set to 1 without collision, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> mov ax, 3
> mov ah, 0
> mov al, 3
> ```

What are these instructions supposed to do?
I'm guessing you forgot to write `int 10h` to setup the 80x25 text video mode?

---

The basic errors in your program (all covered in comments by [Ped7g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4271923/ped7g)) were that you only initialized the `CL` register as your loop counter where the `loop` instruction depends on the whole `CX` register, and that furthermore you erroneously modified it so you could use `CX` for a second purpose.

---

> ... print the 'l' from (0,0) to (0,10) ...

- To get an efficient program you put as much instructions as you can outside of the loop. The repetition count in `CX`, the display page in `BH`, the display attribute in `BL`, and the column in `DL` are all invariant during the entire loop and thus can be placed outside of it.
- You also should refrain from using the `loop` instruction since it's not terribly fast these days.
- When you need to put values in byte-sized registers like `AL` and `AH`, you should strive to do so in a single operation using the word-sized `AX` register. The same applies for `BX`, `CX`, and `DX` registers.

Next code applies the above:

```
    ORG  256
    mov  ax, 0003h        ;BIOS.SetVideoMode AH=00h, Mode 80x25 AL=3
    int  10h
    mov  bx, 000Fh        ;Display page BH=0, Display attribute BL=0Fh
    mov  cx, 1            ;Repetition count CX=1
    mov  dx, 0A00h        ;Row DH=10, Column DL=0
print:
    mov  ah, 02           ;BIOS.SetCursor
    int  10h 
    mov  ax, 0900h + 'l'  ;BIOS.DisplayCharacter AH=09h, Character AL='l'
    int  10h
    dec  dh               ;Go one row up
    jns  print            ;Will stop when DH becomes -1
    ret                   ;Back to DOS (works for a .COM program)
```